# How can I query this as I want?

Tags: sql, string, select, pivot

I have three table like this:

**Product**

```
|   ID | Name    |
+----------------+
| 1  | Product A |
| 2  | Product B |
```

**ProductDescription**

```
|          ID | Description          |
+------------------------------------+
| 1  | Product A English Description |
| 2  | Product A Spanish Description |
| 3  | Product B English Description |
| 4  | Product B Spanish Description |
```

And finally a table to connect 2 above table

**ProductProductDescription**

```
| ProductID | ProductDescriptionID |
+----------------------------------+
| 1         | 1                    |
| 1         | 2                    |
| 2         | 3                    |
| 2         | 4                    |
```

When I joined 3 above table normally, I got this

```
|       ProductID | ProductDescripton       |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 1         | Product A English Description |
| 1         | Product A Spanish Description |
| 2         | Product B English Description |
| 2         | Product B Spanish Description |
```

***But I want to query into this:***

```
|           ProductID | English Description | Spanish Description           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1         | Product A English Description| Product A Spanish Description  |
| 2         | Product B English Description| Product B Spanish Description  |
```

Can you help me?

Comment: what's your DBMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select ppd.id, 
    max(case when pd.description like '%English%' then pd.description end) english_description,
    max(case when pd.description like '%Spanish%' then pd.description end) spanish_description
from ProductProductDescription ppd
inner join ProductDescription pd on pd.id = ppd.productdescriptionid
group by ppd.id
```

Notes:

- design-wise, it would be far better to have another column in product description table that represents the language of the description, rather than relying on the description itself
- you don't need the `product` table to generate the expected result; but if you do, then just add another join to the query

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `PIVOT` Clause (*if available for your DBMS*) as

```
SELECT *
  FROM
  (
    SELECT ppd.ProductID, pd.Description, LTRIM(REPLACE(pd.Description,p.Name)) AS Title
      FROM ProductDescription pd
      JOIN ProductProductDescription ppd
        ON ppd.ProductDescriptionID = pd.ID
      JOIN Product p
        ON ppd.ProductID = p.ID 
   )
 PIVOT 
 (
  MAX(Description) FOR Title IN ('English Description' AS " English Description",
                                 'Spanish Description' AS " Spanish Description") 
 )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=eb7beef09782d3aa59b4c618536cd5e5)</kbd>